# Why does my NSArray get deallocated?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to understand Automatic Reference Counting, as I come from a high-level programming language (Python) and I'm working on a project which use this feature of Objective-C. I often get problems with ARC deallocating objects which I need later, but now I got a concrete example for which I hope I'll get an explanation.

```
- (void) animateGun:(UIImageView *)gun withFilmStrip:(UIImage *)filmstrip{
  NSMutableArray *frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSInteger framesno = filmstrip.size.width / gun_width;
  for (int x=0; x<framesno; x++){
    CGImageRef cFrame = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(filmstrip.CGImage, CGRectMake(x * gun_width, 0, gun_width, gun_height));
    [frames addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cFrame]];
    CGImageRelease(cFrame);
  }
  gun.image = [frames objectAtIndex:0];
  gun.animationImages = frames;
  gun.animationDuration = .8;
  gun.animationRepeatCount = 1;
  [gun startAnimating];
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,(arc4random() % 300)/100 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(),^{
    [self animateGun:leftGun withFilmStrip:[self getFilmStripForAction:gunShoot andTeam:nil withWeapon:nil]];
  });
}
```

The idea behind this snippet of code is simple: I have a `(UIImageView*)gun` which I animate with the images stored in `(NSMutableArray *)frames`, at random times. `(UIImage *)filmstrip` is just an image which contains all the frames which will be used on animation. The first iteration of animation works, but the problems appears on the second iteration, where I get `-[UIImage _isResizable]: message sent to deallocated instance ...` or `-[UIImage _contentStretchInPixels]: message sent to deallocated instance ...` or `-[NSArrayI release]: message sent to deallocated instance ...`. This happens at

```
gun.animationImages = frames;
```

but I don't understand why. I'm not requesting a fix for my issue, but just to help me understand what's happening here. Thanks.

Comment: Code for How do you call this function ? multiple times being called ?

Comment: First time I call it with `[self animateGun:leftGun withFilmStrip:[self getFilmStripForAction:gunShoot andTeam:nil withWeapon:nil]];` and then I just leave the `dispatch_after` to do its job.

Comment: To me it seems like the UIImageView and UIImage references are the problem and that the error lies outside this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARC is a mechanism that removes the need to manually retain/release objects. Here's a nice site that explains how this works: http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/

Try changing "leftGun" for "gun". I think that's probably the one that gets deallocated at some point, if you're using it through an ivar. Otherwise, leftGun simply isn't in the scope.

Here's what it should look like:

In your .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *leftGun;
```

In your .m file:

```
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,(arc4random() % 300)/100 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(),^{
    [self animateGun:gun withFilmStrip:[self getFilmStripForAction:gunShoot andTeam:nil withWeapon:nil]];
  });
```

Also, not quite sure where "gunShoot" is coming from. Is that supposed to be an enum?

**EDIT**

Added an example of how the `leftGun` property should be defined. The reason behind using a property over an ivar is for memory management purposes. If you want to release or destroy an object that is a property, simply set it to nil and the property will take care of releasing the object if it has to.

Comment: But isn't `frames` recreated on every call of the function?

Comment: Ah! You're right. But, where are `leftGun` and `gunShoot` declared?

Comment: leftGun is an IBOutlet declared in the `@interface` of class. `gunShoot` is just an item in an `enum`, which is used to decide which image to use in `getFilmStripForAction` http://pastebin.com/fBu1mUZ2

Comment: Show me the declaration for leftGun. Are you using a property?

Comment: `__weak IBOutlet UIImageView *leftGun;`. No, I don't use a property (should I)?

Comment: Yes, you should. Also, why are you using a weak reference? Weak won't retain your object. Turn it into the following: `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *leftGun` and everywhere you refer to `leftGun`, change it to `self.leftGun`.

Comment: Well, first I used default (strong) references, but as I still got issues with deallocations, I thought that this could be the problem (when adding an IBOutlet from Interface Designer, the default type in __weak). As I said, I get difficulties in understanding this ARC thing

Comment: ARC is simply a mechanism that inserts release calls on objects automatically at the end of a given scope, so you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Well, seems that somehow `-(void)animateGun:withFilmStrip:{` was called from another thread... Using `dispatch_get_main_queue()` instead of `dispatch_get_current_queue()` solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You may prevent the deallocation of the `frames` array if you mark it as `__block`.

```
  __block NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray array];
```

see [“The __block Storage Type.”](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6)

Comment: The array isn't used inside the block, and it's not the array that's being released early anyways. It seems to be the objects in the array.

Comment: The array is used inside the block as a reference from `gun.animationImages = frames;` which is holding references of the images.

Comment: That part isn't inside a Block.